# how to make a asynctasc work and dismiss after sometime?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, while-loop

I have a asynctask and I want to make it to be canceled after some time, 60 sec for example.
I think I have to it inside a while statemant, but I dont know how to count the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my idea:

```
public class ThreadWithAutoCancel extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public ThreadWithAutoCancel(int timeOut) {
        WatchDog watchDog = new WatchDog(this);
        watchDog.execute(timeOut);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Do the job
        return null;
    }

    class WatchDog extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void>{

        private long startTime;
        private AsyncTask task;

        public WatchDog(AsyncTask taskToStop){
            task = taskToStop;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            while(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 < startTime+params[0]){

            }
            task.cancel(true);
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using handler. For example this code will show "Completed" on TextView with R.id.mytext after asynctask will execute for 60 seconds:

```
final int FINISH = 1;
Thread waitingThread;
MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask;
Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == FINISH)
        {
            myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext)).setText("Completed");
        }
    };
};

// ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    waitingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);

                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(FINISH);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
    myAsyncTask.execute();
    waitingThread.start();
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (true) {
              // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to do it with Asynctask.

Comment: I am using handler only for waiting for 60 second. Why you need to wait for one asynctask waiting for another? in my post i do the task with asynctask and the handler just waits for 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

After starting the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), hold a reference to it and call cancel on it 60 seconds later, perhaps on a UI Thread `Handler`. Inside your `doInBackground` method you will have to make sure you return if `isCancelled` returns true. I hope the following snippet will help:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler;
    private AsyncTask<?, ?, ?> mTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        mTask = new MyCustomTask();
        mTask.execute(1, 2, 3);
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTask.cancel();
            }, 60L);
    }
}
```

And inside your custom task:

```
public class MyCustomTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Float, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        String output = "";
        for (Integer i : params) {
            // Check status for each param
            if (isCancelled()) {
                return output;
            }

            ...
         }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String result) {
        // This bit runs on the UI thread
        ...
    }
```

Comment: postDelayed expects milliseconds, not seconds.